# How to prevent a gnome shell extension from updating

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, extension

I use dash to dock extension but there is a quite siginificant bug in the latest version. I downloaded the last version and installed that but the extensions apps automatically upgrades it to the latest version once I log out. How can I turn off auto updates?

Note: I've turned off checking for updates in the browser extension. My browser extension settings are:-

[image: Settings]

Comment: A temporary thing is rename the extension folder to any and use same as `uuid:` in `metadata.json` file

Comment: That works for now!